# Swagger 2.0 - Structural error at definitions.testPOST should NOT have additional properties

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I am trying to add an array in my swagger 2.0 but I keep getting the following error:

```
Structural error at definitions.testPOST
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: testRequests
```

I've checked the swagger documentation but I don't know what I am doing wrong. I could delete 'testRequests' but I need it.

The code is as follows:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: v1
  title: testAPI
security:
  - default: []
paths:
  /testPOST:
    post:
      summary: test
      description: test
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: Payload
          description: test
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/testPOST'
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Success
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              status:
                type: string
                description: HTTP statuscode
              title:
                type: string
                description: Success
              detail:
                type: string
                description: Empty
        '401':
          description: No access
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              status:
                type: string
                description: HTTP statuscode
              title:
                type: string
                description: Message invalid
              detail:
                type: string
                description: Error message
        '500':
          description: Server error
      security:
        - default:
            - testRequest
      x-auth-type: Application & Application User
      x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
      x-wso2-application-security:
        security-types:
          - oauth2
        optional: false
    x-auth-type: Application & Application User
    x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
securityDefinitions:
  default:
    type: oauth2
    authorizationUrl: 'https://test.com'
    flow: implicit
    scopes:
      testRequest: Scope
    x-scopes-bindings:
      testRequest: 'testRequest,admin'
definitions:
  testPOST:
    testRequests:
      type: array
      items:
        type: object
        properties:
          sourceUrl:
            type: string
            example: 'http://example.com/test/1202112'
            description: The reference url.
            default: 'null'
          inboundReferenceNumber:
            type: string
            example: '1234567890'
            description: The request identifier.
            default: 'null'
```

Can somebody please point out what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's before `testPOST:`? Please post the complete snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the request body is supposed to be just an array of objects

```json
[
  {"sourceUrl": ...},
  {"sourceUrl": ...},
  ...
]
```

then the definition should be:

```yaml
definitions:
  testPOST:     # Remove the "testRequests:" line from here
    type: array
    items:
      ..
```

If the request body is supposed to be an object with the `testRequests` property whose value is an array

```json
{
  "testRequests": [
    {"sourceUrl": ...},
    {"sourceUrl": ...},
    ...
  ]
}
```

then the definition should be:

```yaml
definitions:
  testPOST:
    type: object
    properties:
      testRequests:
        type: array
        items:
          type: object
          properties:
            sourceUrl:
              ...
            inboundReferenceNumber:
              ...
```